# How to put a circle ON TOP of a python tkinter window grid and be able to change its position

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

Hi i'm making a game using a 7x7 grid for a school project however I'm struggling to put a circle (for the players and computer token) on top of the grid in each box and be able to move it to different locations of the box. this iis my whole code which I have done so far:

```css
import tkinter as tk

                
        #this is not working (below)
    def create_player():
        #print('Create_player')
        #Canvas.create_oval(1, 1, 1, 1, outline="purple", fill="yellow", width=2)
    # error msg : "name 'Canvas' is not defined"

create_player()
```

When it is run it displays a tkinter window displaying two buttons saying 'Start' and 'EXIT'. (ive cut this out)

When 'Start' is pressed the window closes and opens a new window with an orange and green 7x7 grid with a yellow back ground, the error is shown on line 292 I have written the error underneath it. What I am planning to do is to put the circle on the bottom left box and move it across a number of spaces (from when I roll the in game dice (havent made yet) ) and every eight spaces it goes up instead of across and changes its direction...(also cut this out)

*I need a circle to go on top of the grid and move about ...*

I know how to do the dice btw

Here is full code on GitHub: https://github.com/KoolOllie2002/summer_coding_project_7x7_grid

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This code doesn't execute.. Please provide the real indentation as you have it in your code (because the way you indented might be crucial to why it is not working).

Comment: @campovski thanks for your comment, are you running the snippet in the python program or in browser as it runs for me in python program but my browser...

Comment: I copied it to my machine and run it from terminal. It says expected indent block at `if __name__ ==  '__main__'`. Also I don't know what `if __name__ ==  '__main__'` is doing inside a function...

Comment: @campovski Oh yes that's strange, it was working earlier, I just checked too and its now not working for me! im going to try an fix it and add a new version to the comments

Comment: This seems like way too much code for the problem you seem to be having. Please can you review this and amend as needed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Cheers @EthanField i'm new to stackoverflow and just getting to grips with it ill have a look and shrink it down :-)

Comment: Welcome to the community! Unfortunately most people (myself included) are too lazy or too busy to read through a mountain of code. The less code you post and the more specific and generic it is the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice @EthanField  ! :-)

Comment: I don't think you understood the point of the MCVE, we need something which is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. This is certainly minimal but not complete or verifiable. We need to be able to run the code that you're providing. At the moment your code simply throws up an "Unexpected indent" error. Can you please provide us the smallest amount of code possible which gives you the error you initially had when you asked the question?

Comment: I will take a look at your project (it's just one file)... Be back soon

Comment: @campovski  just been looking at my code and fixed it its on the git hub link its the 0.013 one

Comment: Great, glad you solved it yourself! Please post an answer describing what you have changed and mark it as accepted answer. This way people won't come wondering around this question, trying to answer an already answered question and losing time by it.

Comment: @campovski I fixed why it wasn't executing however havent found out how to add a circle on top of the boxes and to move when random numbers are generated ( a dice )